# list comprehension for multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Is it possible to convert a loop like this into a list comprehension?

```
lst_a = []
lst_b = []
lst_c = []
    
test_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4} 

for k, v in test_dict.items():
    lst_a.append(k)
    lst_b.append(k.upper())
    lst_c.append((k+k))
```

For example, to something like this:

```
lst_a, lst_b, lst_c = [list comprehension logic here for the above loop]
```

**Note:** The output must be three separate lists like the one in the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with `zip()`:

```
test_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

lst_a, lst_b, lst_c = zip(*[(k, k.upper(), k+k) for k in test_dict])

# Convert them to list
# lst_a, lst_b, lst_c = map(list, zip(*[(k, k.upper(), k+k) for k in test_dict)])) 

# Iterate this dict three times.
# lst_a, lst_b, lst_c = ([k for k in test_dict], [k.upper() for k in test_dict], [k + k for k in test_dict])
print(lst_a,lst_b,lst_c)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Simplest approach using a list comprehension

```
lst_a = []
lst_b = []
lst_c = []
    
test_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4} 

[[lst_a.append(k), lst_b.append(k.upper()), lst_c.append(k+k)] for k in test_dict]

print(lst_a, lst_b, lst_c)
```

output -
`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']`

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice to use a list comprehension for its side effects - and it's also inefficient, as you also build a list of lists of `None` that you'll just throw away immediately afterwards.